# how to compare two directories and output the changed file in python

Tags: python, compare

I have two directories in Linux in which I have two files. I need to compare these two directories and print out the changed file.

```
folder1:
  file1.txt   file2.txt

folder2:
  file1.txt   file2.txt
```

I need to compare `folder1` with `folder2` and print out the file name which is not the same in these two directories. I thought of first using `ls` command to get the list of the files and put them in a `list` and then compare them using python's `filecmp`, something like below:

```
import os
import filecmp

folder1_path = "/home/user/folder1/"
folder2_path = "/home/user/folder2/"

def ls(path):
   all = []
   walked = os.walk(path)
   for base, sub_f, files in walked:           
       for sub in sub_f:           
            entry = os.path.join(base,sub)
            entry = entry[len(path):].strip("\\")
            all.append(entry)

       for file in files:          
           entry = os.path.join(base,file)
           entry = entry[len(path):].strip("\\")
           all.append(entry)
    all.sort()
    return all

def folder_diff(folder1_path, folder2_path):
    folder1_list = ls(folder1_path)
    folder2_list = ls(folder2_path)

    for item1, item2 in zip(folder1_list, folder2_list):
        res = filecmp.cmp(folder1_path + item1, folder2_path + item2)

data = folder_diff(folder1_path, folder2_path)
print(data)
```

This is throwing an error `FileNotFound` while file is present in both the folders. Can anyone please suggest any update on this. Thanks

Comment: In the Function folder_diff, what are the content stored in folder1_list, are those just the file names or full file path of the file names, because python needs full file path to access the file

Comment: @SuryaTej Thanks surya. Yes this was the mistake. I have now given full path and it is working.

Comment: @SuryaTej. Please have a look at the code again and review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have only one function you could use this:

```
def folder_diff():
    folder1 = os.listdir(PATH1) # folder containing your files
    folder2 = os.listdir(PATH2) # the other folder

    for item1 in folder1:
        for item2 in folder2:
            if(item1==item2):
                res = filecmp.cmp(PATH1+item1, PATH2+item2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
import os
import filecmp
PATH1 = ''
PATH2 = ''
data = folder_diff()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for `os.listdir`. I just have 1 question for this. I have `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. I want to compare `file1.txt` of folder1 with `file1.txt` of folder2 and same for file2. Will it results in this `folder1 = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']` & `folder2 = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']` always and not  `folder1 = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']` & `folder2 = ['file2.txt', 'file1.txt']` so that I dont compare file1 with file2

Comment: @SAndrew: If the filenames are changed, how would you know which files to compare with each other. In the answer, `if item1==item2`, why do you need comparison again in the first place?

Comment: @Mechanic file name will not change, I just want to compare file1 with file1 only.

Comment: Ok. I thought you wanted to compare the filenames (not the files)

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this using the `glob` module

```
import os
import glob
import filecmp

comparison = []
for each in glob.glob('home/user/folder1/**'):
    for each1 in glob.glob('home/user/folder2/**'):
        if os.path.basename(each) == os.path.basename(each1):
            comparison.append(filecmp.cmp(each, each1))

print(comparison)
```

Comment: Instead of looping through entire folder2 for every file in folder1 to find out whether it also exists in folder2, you could just just use `os.path.exists`. That way you don't need to have nested loops and you will probably speed up the program significantly if both folders contain a lot of files.

Comment: I tried the pathlib version for your suggestion, Path('somepath').exists(), and it was several orders of magnitude faster than doing two loops. Thanks for your comment.